# How to find radio group checked property

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

Here, I've three radio group in a single page. But in the entire page I want to select only one radio option. Like if I'm selecting Monday then Tuesday selection should be unchecked automatically. How can I proceed with the logic, below logic is not working as expected.

sample JSON :

```
{
report:[
{
day:'Monday',
slot:[
'9-10am',
'10-11am',
'11-12am'
]
},{
day:'Tuesday',
slot:[
'9-10am',
'10-11am',
'11-12am'
]
},{
day:'Wednesday',
slot:[
'9-10am',
'10-11am',
'11-12am'
]
}
]}
```

JS code

```
for(var I=0; I<reports.length; I++){
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
if(radios[I].type === 'radio' && radios[I].checked){
document.getElementById(radios[I].id).checked = false
}
```

Comment: would help to see your html with the radio groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to create radio buttons in SurveyJS, you should be able to give the button group a name, so there would be no need for any additional JavaScript. Check out [their documentation](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=questiontype-radiogroup&platform=jQuery#content-js) for an example.

Looks like the sort of nested structure you have for the buttons could be achieved with something like a [dynamic panel](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=questiontype-paneldynamic&platform=jQuery&theme=defaultV2#content-js) or [cascading conditions](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library?id=condition-cascade&platform=jQuery&theme=defaultV2#content-js) in SurveyJS. You should be able to render the available time slots dynamically with `"visibleIf"` based on the selected day.

I would definitely dig around the documentation of SurveyJS to find a solution there rather than hacking your way around it. But solely as an exercise, the problem in your current code could be that you're selecting a button by ID, which will not work correctly if you have tried to give the same ID to multiple buttons. After all, you already have the target button as `radios[I]`, so you could just use `radios[I].checked = false`. Or the issue could be that you're unchecking the selected button AFTER the new selection has been made, which might actually uncheck the button you just clicked. Hard to say without additional information, but in any case, looping your inputs based on a value that might be something else than the actual number of inputs (you're using `reports.length`) is probably not the best idea, since that value might be different from the number of inputs in your form, which would mean that not all of them are included in the loop. Here are a couple of examples of what you could do instead:

```js
// Get all radio buttons
const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')

// If you need to uncheck the previously selected one (don't do this if you can avoid it!)
radioButtons.forEach(radioButton => {
  // Use a mousedown event instead of click
  // This gives you time to uncheck the previous one before the new one gets checked
  radioButton.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    // Get the currently selected button and uncheck it
    const currentlySelected = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked')
    if (currentlySelected) currentlySelected.checked = false
  })
})

// You can add further options to the querySelector, such as [name]
// This gets the currently selected button in the specified group
const checkedRadioButton = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="group-name"]:checked')
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhelminen/r5n3Lwxb/23/) demonstrating this sort of "fake" radio button functionality (without a "name" attribute).

Comment: Hi, As per your suggestion the logic is working now there is some slight modification in the application. https://jsfiddle.net/wv56j7en/ - In this fiddle, I added a checkbox if a user selects the checkbox then I need to clear all the radio selections. If the radio is selected then I need to uncheck the checkbox selected value. I done the changes with if condition it's working but every second time click only it's clear the value. second scenario is if check box is selected then I want all the radio group should be cleared from the UI. Is this possible to implement? Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Here is the condition I used for the checkbox 

`const checkboxButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')

    const currentlySelected = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked')

    if (currentlySelected) currentlySelected.checked = false`

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your problem with only every second click working, but I think it might have something to do with the last radio button and the checkbox having the same id... Anyway, [here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/rhelminen/m3w7vytz/24/) of something along those lines, where the checkbox controls the radio buttons. This just hides the radio buttons, but you could use `remove()` instead if you want to actually remove the radio buttons from the DOM.

Comment: `if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked')) {
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked'))
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
          const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
          radioButtons.forEach(radioButton => {
            radioButton.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
              survey.getQuestionByName(options.name).clearValue()
            })
          })
        }
      }`
I have altered your code

Comment: This code is for checkbox - 
      
`if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')) {
        const checkButtons = document.querySelectorAll(
          'input[type="checkbox"][name=sf_none_works]'
        )
        checkButtons.forEach(checkButton => {
          checkButton.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
            survey.getQuestionByName(options.name).clearValue()
          })
        })
      } `

Answer (score 0):

You can give all these radio buttons the same name, then one radio only will be checked.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same but not able to do. Because it's comes under survey js platform.